# Is chrome not blocking all third party cookies?

Tags: web-browser, cookies, chrome, firefox

I opened a website [99acres.com](https://www.99acres.com/) in incognito windows on two browsers on a Macbook. Following are the settings:

###### Chrome

- Version: 100.0.4896.75 (latest)
- Third Party cookies: Disabled

###### Firefox

- Version: 99.0
- Browser privacy: Standard

##### My observation

One difference I observed in the cookies is that Chrome did **NOT** block a cookie whose Domain property is set to `.facebook.com`. SameSite property is set to `None` here. Firefox does not show that Facebook cookie at all. See attached screenshots.

##### Question

So, is this FB cookie not considered a third party cookie because it is still set by *99acres.com*, or is Chrome not doing a good job of blocking certain cookies?

You can verify this yourself by visiting that 99acres website.

###### Chrome cookies for 99acres.com

[image: Chrome cookies for 99acres.com]

###### Firefox cookies for 99acres.com

[image: Firefox cookies for 99acres.come]